# Как установить обработчик событий на select?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Моя первая настоящая HTML-страничка</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
<body>
    <select id="select">
        <option value="one">Один</option>
        <option value="two">Два</option>
        <option value="three">Три</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" value="">
</body>
<script>
    var select = document.getElementById("select");
    var elements = select.options;      
    var input = document.querySelector("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].addEventListener("click", func);
    }

    function func() {
        input.value = this.innerHTML;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Надо сделать чтобы при клике на один из option, в input вставлялся option.innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавлять обработчик к всему элементу select, а не к каждому элементу option. Помимо этого у элемента option нет события click...

```js
var select = document.getElementById("select");     
var input = document.querySelector("input");

select.addEventListener("change", function(){
  // Если нужно value
  // input.value = this.value;
  // Если нужен текст
  input.value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
});
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="one">Один</option>
  <option value="two">Два</option>
  <option value="three">Три</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="">
```

Comment: я хочу чтоб не value  выводилось а innerHTML

Comment: @КамранРаджабов обновил ответ